# Is it possible to send an registration email confirmation to 2 recipients?

Tags: civievent

We are working on an event registration and would like to have the option to have the email confirmation sent to more than one email address.

In some cases an assistant will register people and they want the email to go to the person completing the form and the registrant.

Does anyone have a way to do this?

Using CiviCRM 4.6.26 with WordPress.

Comment: Do you mean the Registrant has more than one email address, and you want it to go to both their Primary email and another email?

Comment: Yes, in some cases an assistant will register people and they want the email to go to the person completing the form and the registrant.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Alphanumeric Text custom data field (call it CC Email) in a set of custom fields used for Participants.  Note the name of your set of custom fields.

Add your CC Email field to a Profile. This will allow the registrant to specify a CC email when registering for your event.

Find the table that was created in your database for your custom field set. Assuming your civicrm tables have 'civicrm_' as a prefix, it will be named something like civicrm_value_mycustomfields_#.  This table will have a column for your CC Email field.

*Override the sendMail() function in CRM/Event/BAO/Event.php:*

Find the section of code in the sendMail() function that deals with adding CC and BCC emails:

```
$sendTemplateParams['cc'] = CRM_Utils_Array::value('cc_confirm', $values['event']);
$sendTemplateParams['bcc'] = CRM_Utils_Array::value('bcc_confirm', $values['event']);
```

After this code, query to see if there is value in your custom CC Email field for the current Participant and add/append the CC Email address.

```
$query = 'SELECT my_cc_email_field FROM civicrm_value_mycustomfields_# where entity_id ='.$participantId;
$dao = CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery($query);
if($dao->fetch()) {
  $ccEmail = $dao->my_cc_email_field;
  if(is_null($sendTemplateParams['cc'])) $sendTemplateParams['cc'] = $ccEmail;
  else $sendTemplateParams['cc'] .= ', '.$ccEmail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Configuration of the Event - in the Thank you and receipting section you should
be able to add cc: recipients

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this would be a "no this is not possible unless you are also using Drupal in which case webform_civicrm could deliver the required"

One work around I can think of, which is pretty manual, is that you

- put the 'assistant's email' custom field in to a new profile
- set that Profile to alert someone when it comes in
- and/or make a smart group of Contacts with a 'not null' field

and them ensure that you send a copy of the receipt to their email